# What is the domain of $\log(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$?

Tags: calculus

I want to find the domain of $f(x)=\log(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$.

Should it be $\frac{1+x}{1-x}>0 \Rightarrow (1+x) \cdot (1-x)>0 \Rightarrow 1+x>0 \text{ and } 1-x>0 \text{ or } 1+x<0 \text{ and } 1-x<0 $ OR can it just be $1+x>0 \text{ and } 1-x>0$,because of the fact that $\log(\frac{1+x}{1-x})$ can be written like that: $\log(1+x)-\log(1-x)$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$ \ln \left ( \frac{ 1+x}{1-x} \right ) = \ln ( 1+x) - \ln ( 1-x) $$

$\ln (y)$ is only defined if $y>0$ thus we see

$$ (1-x) > 0 \implies 1 > x \quad \& \quad (1+x) >0 \implies x > -1$$

If we put this together we get that the domain is just

$$ |x| < 1$$

Comment: A ok...Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

We can write $\displaystyle\log ab=\log a+\log b$ only when all the logarithms remain defined unlike $$\log(-9)+\log(-4)=\log(36)$$

Now, $\displaystyle\log\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)$ will be defined in $\displaystyle0<\frac{1+x}{1-x}<\infty$

Clearly, $\displaystyle(1+x)(1-x)\ne0\iff x\ne\pm1$

$$\frac{1+x}{1-x}>0\iff (1+x)(1-x)>0\iff (x-1)(x+1)<0\iff -1<x<1$$

Comment: How from $(1+x)(1-x)>0$,do we conclude that $-1<x<1$..?I defined $g(x)=1-x^2$,then I found that $g'(x)=0 \Rightarrow x=0$.. So,I found that $g(x)>0$,when $x \in (-\infty,0]$...have I done something wrong??

Comment: @evinda, As $(x-1)(x+1)<0, (x+1)(x-1)$ must be of opposite signs, right?  Check either cases

Comment: So,you mean that it must be :
$$\text{ either } 1+x>0 \text{ and } 1-x<0 \text{ or } 1+x<0 \text{ or } 1-x>0$$

?But,then wouldn't we get at the first case $x>-1,x>1$ and at the second case $x<-1, x<1$ ...or have I done something wrong?

Comment: @evinda, You are right. First case, $x>$max$(-1,1)$ etc.

Comment: So,isn't it possible to find the domain in this way?

Comment: @evinda, That's what I've done

Comment: Ok,I understood it now...Thank you very much!!!